# Is there an alternative to ImageReader

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, image-reader

I'm working on a camera application where you can take a pic and save it. now im finished but realizied that the ImageReader-class is much to slow for my requirements.

Is there another opportuniy to take the pic without an ImageReader?

Comment: you can use **Picasso**, a third party library to load images. you can read more about it https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library

Comment: i dont need to load pictures, i want to render the datas on a surface

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#createCaptureSession(java.util.List%3Candroid.view.Surface%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) has a pretty good description of the options you have.